# Automate steps to embed excel file in powerpoint slide

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I create power point presentation in which i follow below steps to add excel file in the slides:

Insert > Object > Create from file >Browse excel file > Click on "Display as Icon" > Press ok > Rename the excel file to suit the slide.

I tried to link excel file rather then embed it but this power point needs to be circulated to many stakeholders. So they wont be able to open the excel file as it will be linked to excel file on my desktop.

Is there a way to automate this whole process?

Comment: See for example: https://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=4833

Comment: You can record a macro when going through those steps and review the code to optimize it if needed

Comment: thanks for the reply.. @TimWilliams- this example is for adding a screenshot and i want to embed a excel file. I am not expert that i could make such a big edit.

Comment: thank for the reply.. @EmmanuelMurairi - i don't think we can record macro in Power Point 16..

Comment: I see. Can you consider using an external script, like a python script to do the automation for you? There are ways you can manipulate excel files and PowerPoint files programmatically with python or any other language that best suits your case, beside VBA - [VBA isn't being updated](https://datasciencenerd.com/is-vba-worth-learning/)